# Overlapping polygons with buffers and need to keep associated data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlay, union

I have a point file that has been buffered by 400m. I have overlayed it on top of a polygon file and I need to keep all data that overlaps for each point. What is the best way to do this?
I have unioned the 400m buffer (pink in the image) and then the blue selected parts are what I would need to keep for the top two points - but not the bits that overlap for each of the points...I need to do this for 1000's of records. [image]

Comment: I would either do a spatial join on the points and polygons or an intersect. Depending on whether the points/polygons are 1:1 or 1:many. After the attributes are in the point data then buffer.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to "keep" but the usual way of joining attributes from one layer to another is to use the Spatial Join tool. Search Help for that.

Comment: Depending on your license level you may be able to do Intersect http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000 (Some license levels only allow 2 layers at at time) where buffers overlap *multiple* features will be created in the output to match the buffer. This will also embed the attributes of the buffers on the intersecting data to make summation easier.

Comment: I'm unclear on what it is you want to keep, or what attributes you're trying to preserve. You need to keep the selected parts but not the overlaps doesn't make any sense. Unioning may not be what you want to do with those buffers.  I suspect the problem you might have is that some of those selected areas are actually duplicated; or maybe that's what you want. Can you describe what you're trying to do in more general terms?